# Convert c++ string to NSString

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

How do I convert the code bellow to a `NSString`?

```
std::cout << "Cipher Text (" << ciphertext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;

for( int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ ) {

    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << " ";
}

std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
```

I tried :

```
 NSString *cyp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ciphertext.c_str()];
```

But the `cyp` `NSString` is null..

```
NSString *cyp = @(ciphertext.c_str());
NSLog(@"cypher %@",cyp);
NSLog(@"cypher %s",ciphertext.c_str());
```

prints out:

```
Pas[8044:70b] playntext Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide...
2013-11-27 14:38:01.421 Pas[8044:70b] cypher (null)
2013-11-27 14:38:01.422 Pas[8044:70b] cypher ¯≥Íä≥z=(fúóß≥¢P%Ä’“2ŒË
W3ÔpˇHÈËò©¬^ß∞@C°¸#±°Î≤ˆóbp°Å nxÄê
2013-11-27 14:38:01.423 Pas[8044:70b] decrypted Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide...
```

So why can I print it out like a string but can't create a NSString from "ciphertext"

Comment: NSString stringWithCString:encoding: with different encodings.
Also check ciphertext.c_str() return value :)

Comment: Almost certainly the string is not encoded in UTF8

Comment: Or (as appears to be the case on closer examination), it really is ciphertext, in which case it is not a real "string" -- it's not character data.

Comment: To print ciphertext you should print in hex (a separate question) or in Base64.

Answer (score 3):

Try that this works for me:

```
NSString *s1 = @(YOURCSTRING.c_str());
```

Comment: For this answer, you have to pray that your C string uses UTF-8.  If it does, this is the best answer.

Comment: s1 will be `nil` if YOURCSTRING is like `\xffffff80\x02-addListener`, which includes non-UTF-8 character